# Posting answers triggers crash

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I was posting answers on Ask Ubuntu via the Stack Exchange iOS app.

Problem: After any answer submission or edit submission (NOT comment submissions, however), I get an application crash instantly after the 'success' pop up message appears.

Submitting questions does not cause the crash.  Only answers and answer edits.  (Although I just crashed editing this post)

This makes true usability of the app difficult, as I expect it to not crash after posting and just continue to operate.

I am on an iPhone 5, with iOS 8.3.  The app version is 1.3.0.

Comment: Note it seems to randomly affect Question edits now.  Question posting does not seem affected but as there is no test space for me to do a lot of question post testing I can't verify that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was wondering how long until someone asked this. Our crash rate went up drastically when iOS 8.3 came out. The OS has a bug where it tries refocusing the text field from the deallocated editor after you dismiss the alert, crashing the app.

1.3.1 has been in the review queue for a week so I'm hoping it'll be in the store early next week with this and several other crash fixes.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Yep the new App Store build didn't crash when I posted that or tagged your post.

Comment: I have also experienced crashes each time I finish editing a post, even if that post didn't raise a "too lengthy" flag.  Could this also be relevant to the issue in the question?

Comment: Oh, wait.  Someone above already commented about it.  Well then, at least you know it's not just him. ;-)

Comment: @Jamal if you submitted a post, saw an alert, and the app crashed, it was definitely this issue.

Comment: @BrianNickel Maybe [tag:status-inprogress] is required here until Apple releases it?  Maybe an email to their reviewers indicating its a critical fix will expedite processing?

Comment: @ThomasW. The closest tag we have to that is [tag:status-planned]. [tag:status-complete] just means that work has completed and will be shipped.

Comment: @BrianNickel Mmmm... well then that's a tricky situation, because to the end user it looks like nothing has been completed.  But meh.

Comment: @ThomasW. Good news. It's in the store now.

Comment: @BrianNickel That's EXCELLENT news.  Thanks for keeping us updated on that.